# C#/EF - Cannot attach to entity after looking up navigation property in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen several other threads regarding this error, but I can't seem to find one that matches (or solves) my particular situation.

I'm trying to edit a record (a record of a product demonstration), which has a navigation property relating to *0:n* product records.

When submitting the edit form, the demo's previously selected products do not come through in model binding (this is really the crux of my issue).  As such, I have to go out and get the currently assigned products, so that I can calculate which newly assigned products need to be added or removed from the record via the "UpdateSelectedProducts" method.

Doing this throws an error when setting my entity state to modified.

Here's the code for my Edit method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Demo demo, string[] selectedProducts)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the currently assigned products so that we can detect differences
            demo.Products = db.Demos.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.DemoID == demo.DemoID).FirstOrDefault().Products;
            UpdateSelectedProducts(selectedProducts, demo);

            // Update the demo record
            db.Entry(demo).State = EntityState.Modified; // Error is thrown here
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
     }

    private void UpdateSelectedProducts(string[] selectedProductIds, Demo demo)
    {
        var demoProducts = new HashSet<int>(demo.Products.Select(x => x.ProductID));

        foreach (var product in db.Products)
        {
            if (selectedProductIds.Contains(product.ProductID.ToString()))
            {
                if (!demoProducts.Contains(product.ProductID))
                {
                    // Add product to demo if it is selected, and not already part of the demo
                    demo.Products.Add(product);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (demoProducts.Contains(product.ProductID))
                {
                    // Remove the product from the demo if it is part of the demo, but not selected
                    demo.Products.Remove(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Additionally, I've tried using AsNoTracking() with a Where clause, but that gets me the same results.

Any thoughts?

> Attaching an entity of type 'CPPv2.Models.Demo' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This
>   can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

Comment: I guess you dont need to calculate and select a particular set of Products. Just add both the selected and the new Products to the navigations property ( all new ones will be automatically added). You  don't need to modify the state. You should let it track

Comment: I did try removing the "db.Entry(demo).State = EntityState.Modified" line.  This allowed the products to be saved, but the scalar values did not save.

Comment: "When submitting the edit form, the demo's previously selected products do not come through in model binding": if that is the issue then you should solve that instead of just blindly trying things until something works. You see that gets you into all sort of other troubles. Show the code for your view, the model you are passing to your view and that is where your problem is. Only show the relevant part of the view.